# I am not able to scrape the web data from the given website using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Hi I ans trying to scrape the data from the site https://health.usnews.com/doctors/city-index/new-jersey . I want all the city name and again from the link scrape the data. But using requests library in python something is going wrong. There are some session or cookies or something which is stopping to crawl the data. please help me out.

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'https://health.usnews.com/doctors/city-index/new-jersey'
>>> html_content = requests.get(url)
>>> html_content.status_code
403
>>> html_content.content
'<HTML><HEAD>\n<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>Access Denied</H1>\n \nYou don\'t have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;health&#46;usnews&#46;com&#47;doctors&#47;city&#45;index&#47;new&#45;jersey" on this server.<P>\nReference&#32;&#35;18&#46;7d70b17&#46;1528874823&#46;3fac5589\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n'
>>>
```

Here is the error I am getting.

Comment: Are you running this code from your computer or a server?

Comment: From my computer

Comment: Hmmm strange, do you still have the problem?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with [fake-useragent](https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/)  lib also also

Comment: have you tried using a proxy? and when you visit the site does it still look fine?

Comment: es site looks fine .. I don't know how to used proxy .

Comment: I'll post an answer where I explain everything just give me a sec.

Comment: I just posted my answer, I know everyone suggested you to use a header but please do try running the code I posted. (PS: I tried using the header from the previous answer and I also got an error)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add header in your request so that the site think you are a genuine user.

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
html_content = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: I have tried with header also even then it is not working.

Comment: it has default header   User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36 even that also not working .

Comment: it worked for me. may be u are making too many calls and this site blocked your ip. u can try from some server with different ip. they might also do a temporary ip block if u make too many call in sort period of time. in later case u can add some delay in your code.

Comment: on a recheck it seems popular server ips are blocked i tried running from heroku and aws, got this header in response `{'Content-Length': '312', 'Expires': 'Wed, 13 Jun 2018 10:45:28 GMT', 'Server': 'AkamaiGHost', 'Connection': 'close', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0', 'Date': 'Wed, 13 Jun 2018 10:45:28 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Mime-Version': '1.0'}`. see the server in response 'AkamaiGHost'. u will have to figure out a way to fool akami request filter here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Like the previous answer suggested I would recommend you to add a header to your code, so your code should look something like this:

```
import requests
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0'}
url = 'https://health.usnews.com/doctors/city-index/new-jersey'
html_content = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
html_content.status_code
print(html_content.text)
```

Comment: I have used this code also but the same error I am getting

Comment: No I just posted with the header I found in the web page using inspect ...

Comment: can you please literally copy past the code that I posted and tell me if you are getting the same error

Comment: @rofelia09 and the header that you are using isn't the same as the one that I put in the answer (It tried using your header and I get the same error as you)

Comment: But using your header also I am getting same error.

Comment: Did you literally copy past my code and run it (without change anything)?

Comment: try raplcying your current `html_content = requests.get(url, headers=headers)` with this `html_content = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies = {"https":"177.92.4.70:80"})`

Comment: Please check my update post ... some proxies error is referring .

Comment: Okay no problem .. I will hunt the solution one day..  Thanks